# Probability of finding the odd marble

Tags: probability

Assume we have an urn with n-1 red marbles and only 1 green. Find the probability to draw the green marble after Z consecutive draws, if we draw one marble at a time, without replacement.

In the first draw, the probability is 1/n. In the second draw, it is 1/(n-1) and so on, until the Zth draw, 1/(n-Z+1), right?
Which distribution does it follow? Is it hypergeometric?

Comment: No...try the second draw again.  You'll see the pattern.  don't forget:  in order to get the green on the second draw you need to have  failed to get it on the first.

Comment: Just intuitively, what is the chance of getting the green ball on the, say, 7th draw vs the chance of getting it on the, say, 13th draw? If you still don't see it: suppose I distribute all the $n$ marbles among $n$ people, where each person gets 1 marble ... does the order matter how I hand out the marbles? And what should be the sum of all the probabilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are looking for the probability of drawing the green marble exactly on the $Z$-th draw, right?

Well, if you think about this just intuitively, the chance of drawing the green ball on the 7th draw should be the same as drawing it on the 13th draw: the problem is equivalent to randomly distributing the marbles to $n$ different people; clearly everyone has a $\frac{1}{n}$ chance of getting the green  marble.

Indeed, note that the sum of all probabilities should add up to $1$, which is *not* the case with your calculations. In fact, for the last draw you have $Z=n$, and so by your formula you would have a probability of $\frac{1}{n-Z+1}=\frac{1}{n-n+1}=\frac{1}{1}=1$ of drawing the green marble on the last draw.... clearly not right! But if the chance is $\frac{1}{n}$, then clearly the probabilities do add up to $1$.

Ok, but why doesn't the order matter? If I hand out the marbles one by one, why wouldn't the 7th person not have some kind of advantage or disadvantage compared to the 13th person? How does the math work out so that everyone has exactly $\frac{1}{n}$ probability of getting the green marble?

Well, like you said, to get the marble on the first draw is $\frac{1}{n}$. But to get it on the second draw is to not get it on the first draw and then get it on the next draw. So that would $\frac{n-1}{n}\cdot \frac{1}{n-1}=\frac{1}{n}$.  Now you try to get the right formula for drawing the marble on the third draw ... and you'll see the general pattern.

BY the way, if you meant to find the probabilities of drawing the green marble in any of the first $Z$ draws, then that probability will be $\frac{Z}{n}$. Again, intuitively go back to distributing the marbles among $n$ people: what is the chance that among any $Z$ of them, one has the green marble? GIven that they each have a chance of $\frac{1}{n}$, and given that these are mutually exclusive, you can just add them all up, so you get $\frac{Z}{n}$.

OR, doing the 'one by one' math: the probability to get the green marble on either of the first two draws is 1 minus the probability of not getting it on either draw, so that would be $1-\frac{n-1}{n}\cdot \frac{n-2}{n-1}=1-\frac{n-2}{n}=\frac{2}{n}$.  Again, I'll leave it up to you to find the general expression for any $Z$, but note that your formula in your Post does also not match up with these probabiliies.

Comment: I believe the question is asking for the probability of obtaining the green marble during one of the first $Z$ draws.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Yeah, this wasn't clear ... I did clarify how I interpreted the question.  But I'll add the other interpretation.

Comment: @all: thank you very much for your replies. Actually I refer to the probability to find the green marble after Z draws (I assume that once I found it, I stop drawing more marbles!!).

Comment: @MariusStephant ... which is thus the same as drawing it on exactly the $Z$-th draw.  So that was my initial interpretation. DId you find the general formula that shows it is always $\frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: @Bram28: Yes, I understand that the probability at the 2nd draw is conditional and depends on the result of the first draw. That is, to find the green ball at the 2nd draw, this has probability 1/(n-1) provided that the result of the previous draw was negative (with probability (n-1)/n. I also understand that the hypergeometric distribution does not apply here, right? (although the formula works).

Comment: @MariusStephant Right, but do you also see what the formula would be for $Z =3$? And how it always works for any $ Z$?  ANd yes, the hypergeometric distribution does not apply here since getting a 'success' in this case in one draw is mutually exclusive from getting a success on a different draw.

Comment: @Bram28: So which distribution applies? For Z=3 we would have a probability of 1/(n-2)*[(n-1)/n*(n-2)/(n-1)] - is this correct?

Comment: @MariusStephant It's called the discrete uniform distribution.

Comment: Ohh I see, thanks a lot!!